# if (iAmNull != null && iAmNull.Length == 6) Do();

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if the first part of an if-structure is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864500/what-happens-if-the-first-part-of-an-if-structure-is-false)

if the first criterion yields false in an AND, is the second condition evaluated at all in c# ?

i.e. is a NullException thrown in this example?

```
if (iAmNull != null && iAmNull.Length == 6) Do();
```

Comment: As others have pointed out `&&` operator short-circuits so that the second expression is not evaluated. On case where you need both expressions to be evaluated use the `&` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the second condition is not evaluated because you are using the short-circuit && operator.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

> Short-circuit evaluation, minimal evaluation, or McCarthy evaluation
>   denotes the semantics of some Boolean operators in some programming
>   languages in which the second argument is only executed or evaluated
>   if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the
>   expression: when the first argument of the AND function evaluates to
>   false, the overall value must be false; and when the first argument of
>   the OR function evaluates to true, the overall value must be true.

Answer (score 0):

No, the logical operators have [short-circuit evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).