# In C whether the second part of if structure is executed if first logical part failed? Is the behavior compiler depended?

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-construction

Extending the question 
[What happens if the first part of an if-structure is false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864500/what-happens-if-the-first-part-of-an-if-structure-is-false)

for C programming

```
if((NULL!=b)&&(query(&b)))
```

In the above code will the part "query(&b)" is executed if b=Null? 
And is the behavior consistent across compilers?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958864/c-is-there-lazy-evaluation-when-using-operator-as-in-c. In a word: the operator will short-circuit and it is standard C behavior.

Comment: The language used in this question is inaccurate and ambiguous. I would have assumed that the "second part" of an if *construct* or *statement* (not *structure*) was the `else` part.  Here you are merely talking about the *left-hand side of a boolean operation* - the `if` construct is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but the credit should really go to someone else (like paxdiablo who posted first) as I merely wanted to add a reference for clarity and others put a lot more time into their answers.

Comment: @jpw, the credit should go to the _best_ answer, not the first. It's just unfortunate that I got called away before getting to the standards doc. The best answer for language questions like this is almost _always_ the one that quotes the standard, so yours is well deserved. In any case, it's not like I need the rep :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo +1 to you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, logical operators in C will short-circuit.

If you attempt to evaluate `a && b` when `a` is false, `b` is not evaluated.

But keep in mind that you're not checking `b` with that original statement, rather you're checking `a`. Also note that it's safe to take the address of a variable that's NULL, you just can't dereference it.

I suspect what you should be writing is:

```
if ((b != NULL) && (query (*b)) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the correct answers already posted this is what the C99 standard says (section 6.5.13 Logical AND operator, paragraph 4):

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the
>   evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares equal
>   to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

> In the above code will the part "query(&b)" is executed if b=Null?

Simple answer NO. It will not be executed. `&&` is [short circuited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So  if you try to do so, this will break the short circuit evaluation, and is therefore not reccomended.

Check [FAQ3.6](http://c-faq.com/expr/shortcircuit.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is not specific to the `if` statement, but rather to *boolean expressions* in general.

In `a && b`, `b` is not evaluated if `a` is false.

Similarly in `c || d`, `d` is not evaluated if `c` is true.

This is known as *short-circuit evaluation* and is part of the definition of the language, so will be consistent across compliant compilers.

Comment: I think in the line "In a && b, b is not evaluated if a is true." you mean to say "if a is false"